# OpenSSL: PEM_read_PUBKEY returns NULL

Tags: c++, openssl

I am trying to encrypt some data with a public key which I previously stored in PEM format.
I started with loading the public key from file like this:

```
QString publicKeyFilePath = QString(FILE_PATH);
if (!QFile::exists(publicKeyFilePath))
{
    std::cout << "Doesn't exist." << std::endl;
}

FILE *publicKeyFile = fopen(publicKeyFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), "rb");
EVP_PKEY *publicKey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(publicKeyFile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (publicKey == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "PEM_read_PUBKEY failed." << std::endl;
}
fclose(publicKeyFile);
```

but `PEM_read_PUBKEY` always returns null.

Why could this be?

The contents of the file look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: How about that `publicKeyFile` is non-null and valid? And if it is value, and `PEM_read_PUBKEY` really is returning null, immediately checking `ERR_get_error()` and passing the error code to `ERR_error_string` to fetch the full error string of the failed operation? Debuggers are awesome tools for this, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you! `ERR_error_string` returns `PEM routines: get_name: no start line` - what does this mean?

Comment: Try opening in text rather than binary mode, it could be the line endings are not what openssl is expecting

Comment: Changing `rb` to `r` doesn't help :(

Comment: is `publicKeyFile` valid (not `NULL`)? Was file opened properly?

Comment: That public key is old-school. You're probably going to find using `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey` is your best option, though you'll have to manufacture a `EVP_PKEY*` thereafter from the resulting `RSA*` (which is mostly trivial, but still irritating).

Comment: @WhozCraig What do you mean with `old-school`? I used `RSA_generate_key_ex` and `PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey`

Comment: The key seems valid. `openssl -pubin -RSAPublicKey_in -in <file> -outform -out <newfile>` should be able to convert the old key format into the usual PEM format used by openssl.

Comment: Okay it works with `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey` - thank you!

Comment: @JakobStark Which OpenSSL functions do I have to use to do that in-code?

Comment: "What do you mean with old-school " - I mean the key has an encoded RSAPublicKey key structure in it, not a SubjectPublicKeyInfo. Btw, `PEM_read_PUBKEY` actually does work, at least for me on that specific file you posted, using OpenSSL 3.0.5, so not sure what the original issue was.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am using `OpenSSL 1.1.1`. Do you mind posting some code references how to get an `EVP_PKEY` from an `RSA`?

Comment: @bopeh74638 consider reading the [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey.html) carefully. There are lots of functions, that read and write the keys in different formats. You should match the output format to the input format.

Comment: Yeah, I just confirmed that api, PEM_read_PUBKEY, will NOT work in 1.1.1q on RSAPublicKey pems, at least not that I could muster. It *does* work in 3.0.x. If you're not married to that file format I would suggest (a) using the EVP_PKEY family to generate the key pairs, (b) using PEM_write_PUBKEY and PEM_write_PrivateKey for saving the files, and PEM_read_PUBKEY and PEM_read_PrivateKey for reading them. It will not only be easier, it will be fore-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for `EVP_PKEY *publicKey`  before calling read API's to extract public key. `EVP_PKEY` is a structure which holds the public & private key.

You need to first use the below function:

```
EVP_PKEY *publicKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
```

and then check if `*publicKey` memory is allocated or not. If so then call:

```
PEM_read_PUBKEY()
```

Comment: *you need to allocate memory for EVP_PKEY *publicKey before calling read API's...* No you don't.  In fact, the [**BUGS** section of the OpenSSL documentation for `PEM_read_PUBKEY()` even says that's buggy in some  versions of OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_PUBKEY.html#BUGS): "The PEM read routines in some versions of OpenSSL will not correctly reuse an existing structure. ..."  Read the comment above:  "Okay it works with PEM_read_RSAPublicKey - thank you!"  An *RSA* public key PEM is not the same as a generic `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY` PEM.  The binary ASN.1 data differs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).